# Calculate the number of times a combination is used in a log

Tags: python-3.x

I have a log of events in the bellow form:

```
A B C D
A B C D
A B C D
A B C D
D E F G
D E F G
D E F G
D E F G
D E F G
D E F G
D E F G
A D E F G
D E F G
A D E G
```

I am trying to calculate the frequency of for example how many times `A -> B`.
With the bellow code I calculate the frequency of each trace.

```
from collections import Counter
flog = []
input_file ="test.txt"

with open(input_file, "r") as f:
                for line in f.readlines():
                    line = line.split()
                    flog.append(line)
                trace_frequency= map(tuple,flog)
flog=list(Counter(trace_frequency).items())
```

That gives me :

```
(('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), 4)
(('D', 'E', 'F', 'G'), 8)
(('A', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'), 1)
(('A', 'D', 'E', 'G'), 1)
```

So my question is how can I go from the above to a format where I calculate all instances of the log to the bellow format:

```
    A B 4
    B C 4
    C D 4
    A D 2 
    D E 10...etc
```

Thanks to all for your time.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried and describe what exactly it's doing wrong?

Comment: Does going across lines count? eg from D -> A where A is the beginning of the next line. And if you have `A B C D`, do you count B -> C as well?

Comment: No going across the line does not count.And you also count B->C. Sorry about that I will correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of counting each line as a whole, split each line to pairs then count the appearance of each pair.

For example, instead of counting `('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'`), count `('A', 'B')`, `('B', 'C')`, `('C', 'D')` individually.

```
from collections import Counter

flog = []
input_file = "test.txt"

with open(input_file, "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        line = line.split()
        flog.extend(line[i: i + 2] for i in range(len(line) - 1))
#            ^ note extend instead of append
    trace_frequency = map(tuple, flog)
flog = list(Counter(trace_frequency).items())
```

`flog` is now

```
[(('A', 'B'), 4), (('B', 'C'), 4), (('C', 'D'), 4), (('D', 'E'), 10),
 (('E', 'F'), 9), (('F', 'G'), 9), (('A', 'D'), 2), (('E', 'G'), 1)]
```

To get your desired format (with the bonus of order) you can use:

```
flog = Counter(trace_frequency)

for entry, count in flog.most_common():
    print(' '.join(entry), count)
```

Outputs

```
D E 10
E F 9
F G 9
A B 4
B C 4
C D 4
A D 2
E G 1
```

Comment: Looks good so far. Thank you very much for your time!Just a follow up question. How do I convert the list of tuples to the format that I have shown above?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the best, but one possibility is to use Pandas. Given a file `log.txt` that looks like this:

```
0 1 2 3 4
A B C D
A B C D
A B C D
A B C D
D E F G
D E F G
D E F G
D E F G
D E F G
D E F G
D E F G
A D E F G
D E F G
A D E G
```

This code will work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('log.txt', sep='\s+')

combos = [[(y[1][x], y[1][x + 1]) for x in range(len(df.loc[0]) - 1)] for y in df.iterrows()]
combos = [item for sublist in combos for item in sublist if np.nan not in item]

from collections import Counter
print(Counter(combos))
```

Giving you:

```
('A', 'B') 4
('B', 'C') 4
('C', 'D') 4
('D', 'E') 10
('E', 'F') 9
('F', 'G') 9
('A', 'D') 2
('E', 'G') 1
```